# Schauder basis for a separable Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is known that if a Banach space $X$ has a Schauder basis, then $X$ is separable. On the other hand [P. Enflo](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnd.mcgill.ca%2F~ivan%2FPerEnfloAcounterexampleToTheApproximationProblemInBanachSpaces.pdf&ei=KMNKUtWFLvPd4AO3s4HYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFiKTHj_-PVVJ3uD5tpLHgnDbx7FA&sig2=3PnbwlRQmz2-eg_EV4HNaw&bvm=bv.53371865,d.dmg) showed that there exist a separable Banach space without Schauder basis.

If $X$ is a separable Banach space, then we can find a increasing sequence of finite dimensional subspaces $X_n\subset X$ such that $\cup X_n$ is dense in $X$, hence, we can find a sequence $(x_n)$, such that $x_1,...,x_k$ is a basis of $X_k$ for all $k$.

My question is: What is a necessary condition (and maybe sufficient) in order to show that $(x_k)$ is a Schauder basis for $X$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the necessary and sufficient conditions for a countable linearly independent system of vectors $(e_n)$ to be a Shauder basis of its closed linear span is
$$
\exists K>0\quad \forall (a_n)\subset \mathbb{C}\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall m\leq n\quad\left\Vert\sum\limits_{k=1}^m a_k e_k\right\Vert\leq K\left\Vert \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k e_k\right\Vert
$$
See [Proposition 1.1.9](https://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&pg=PA6) in Topics in Banach space theory by F. Albiac, N. Kalton

Comment: Are there prominent examples where this criterion has actually been used?

Comment: @rmcerafl google Grunblum's criterion